# How can we edit the source code of GNU's gdb debugger?

Tags: linux, gcc, gdb

I am on a Linux(Ubuntu 22) machine with gcc installed. We know that gcc comes with gdb as debugger. There are many commands in gdb and I want to change the behaviour of some inbuilt commands(disp). Can anyone tell me where can I access the source code of gdb in gcc libraries and change it to desired one?

Comment: Are you *sure*? I agree with Stephen's answer, you don't *have* to modify the source code of GDB to achieve that, and quite honestly, it would *not* be the project I'd recommend. Also, you already got the same information in the [identical question](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/14249/how-can-we-edit-the-source-code-of-gnus-gdb-debugger#comment37684_14249), so  working with what people comment before asking the same question again is also a bit appreciated :)

Answer (score 3):

GDB isn’t part of GCC, [it’s a separate project](https://www.sourceware.org/gdb/). On Ubuntu, you can access the source code of the version you have by running

```
apt source gdb
```

You can also [use the upstream repository](https://www.sourceware.org/gdb/current/) if you prefer that.

GDB is extensively customisable, so you might be able to achieve your goals using [extensions](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb.html/Extending-GDB.html#Extending-GDB) instead of modifying its source code. [GDB’s Python API](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb.html/Python-API.html#Python-API) in particular provides many ways of improving the GDB UI; see [this dashboard](https://github.com/cyrus-and/gdb-dashboard) for example:

[image: screenshot of the GDB dashboard showing disassembly, breakpoints, expressions, command history, memory dumps, register contents, source code, the stack, and watched variables]

Answer (score 2):

Enable the source packages in your `sources.list` (The `deb-src` entries) manually or using `sudo add-apt-repository`:, then run `sudo apt update`:

```
sudo add-apt-repository "deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy main restricted universe multiverse"
sudo add-apt-repository "deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-updates main restricted universe multiverse"
sudo add-apt-repository "deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-security main restricted universe multiverse"
sudo apt update
```

to download the source package:

```
apt source gdb
```

or

```
apt-get source gdb
```

Edit, then rebuild your package. [Here is a complete tutorial in the Debian wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/BuildingTutorial)